# RedirectToPage in Razor Task OnGetAsync() is not working

Tags: c#, cookies, razor-pages

So far all potential similar questions that I have read thru don't apply at all.
Neither does searching The Google.
I have a feeling the problem is how the OnGetAsync() is used but for now, anything I try, including Intellisense doesn't work.
It is an interesting block of code because it works without trying to read a cookie. Not because the cookie doesn't work but because I insert a RedirectToPage in the middle of the code, trying to change direction in the OnGetAsync to open my Single City page.
Working version just lists cities to choose from.

**First block of code below works.**

```
        public async Task OnGetA ync(byte ClearChoice)
    {
            //THESE ARE THE CITY ID'S WE ARE DISPLAYING
            var citylist = new int[] { 1, 2, 4 };

            var query = _context.tblCities.AsQueryable();

            query = query.Where(c => citylist.Contains(c.CityID)).OrderBy(c=>c.StateName);

            //AND FINALLY OPEN THE RAZOR PAGE
            Cities = await query.ToListAsync();

}
```

If I throw in a branch statement that fires the RedirectToPage with just one city ID, it skips the redirect and returns the same page with just one city listed versus all 3 cities. "return RedirectToPage" gets skipped over.

Desire is for "/DanceList/ThisCity" to open with only that city in the cookie.

For some reason, between the 2 endings

(RedirectToPage("/DanceList/ThisCity", new { cookieResults });

and Cities = await query.ToListAsync();) something goes wrong.

Clear as mud? Sorry I don't know any other way to ask.

**This block of code doesn't work.**

```
    public async Task OnGetAsync(byte ClearChoice)
    {
        //THESE ARE THE CITY ID'S WE ARE DISPLAYING
        var citylist = new int[] { 1, 2, 4 }; var cookieResults = "";

        cookieResults = Request.Cookies["CityID"];

        if (cookieResults == null)
        {
            //SHOW ALL CITIES

        }
        else
        {
            citylist = new int[] { Int32.Parse(cookieResults) };  //ONE CITY FROM COOKIE

           RedirectToPage("/DanceList/ThisCity", new { cookieResults }); //CODE SKIPS THIS AND CONTINUES ON TO BOTOOM
           
        }

        var query = _context.tblCities.AsQueryable();

        query = query.Where(c => citylist.Contains(c.CityID)).OrderBy(c=>c.StateName);

        //AND FINALLY OPEN THE RAZOR PAGE
        Cities = await query.ToListAsync();
    }
```

Comment: The `RedirectToPage` method is generating a `RedirectToPageResult`. Therefore you need to `return` from your action: `return RedirectToPage("/DanceList/ThisCity", new { cookieResults });`

Comment: Thanks @Rahul Sharma
but return word gets underlined with red and mousing over CS1995 says:
"Encountering error CS1995 means the referenced code includes a return statement that conflicts with the async modifier and the method's return type."  .  .  .  .  The problem is the line of code that opens the current page . . . Cities = await query.ToListAsync(); . . . . is a different Task than the one that wants to redirect. . . . return RedirectToPage("/DanceList/ThisCity", new { cookieResults });

Comment: When I hover over "return" keyword like you suggested and try the potential fix .  .  .  . public async Task<RedirectToPageResult> OnGetAsync(byte ClearChoice) .   .   .   .The "OnGetAsync" word turns  red and when I hover over it it says . . . . ."Not all code paths return a value"

Comment: Check @mike answer. That should solve your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the method signature to return an `IActionResult`, and add `return Page()` to the method so that all code path return a value:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(byte ClearChoice)
{
    var citylist = new int[] { 1, 2, 4 }; var cookieResults = "";
    cookieResults = Request.Cookies["CityID"];
    if (cookieResults == null)
    {
        //SHOW ALL CITIES
    }
    else
    {
       citylist = new int[] { Int32.Parse(cookieResults) };  
       return RedirectToPage("/DanceList/ThisCity", new { cookieResults }); 
    }
    var query = _context.tblCities.AsQueryable();
    query = query.Where(c => citylist.Contains(c.CityID)).OrderBy(c=>c.StateName);
    //AND FINALLY OPEN THE RAZOR PAGE
    Cities = await query.ToListAsync();
    return Page();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul and Mike. I had tried the Task<IActionResult> but "not all paths yada yada". Funny it was a simple "return Page();" that made the second option (all cities) work. Thank you! So much was put into this block just to get ye ol' IN(1,2,4) SQL to work in C# Razor. oi!